# JavaScript - regular expression to check string for capital and lower case letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to validate if surnames doesn't contain all lowercase letter or all uppercase letter, for example: d'Arras, de Clemente

I'm using the following regular expression, however it allow all letter to be uppercase or lowercase

```
/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i
```

What is the best way to validate such surnames? Surname can start from lowercase or upercase but not all letters are upercase or lowercase

Comment: e e cummings begs to differ.

Comment: `/^(?![A-Z ,.'-]+$)(?![a-z ,.'-]+$)[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/`

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Comment: /^(?![A-Z ,.'-]+$)(?![a-z ,.'-]+$)[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/ is perfect, although is there any alternate to ?! ?it seems some browser are not supporting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const
  check = (name, delimiter) =>
    name.split(delimiter).every(part =>
      ![part.toLowerCase(), part.toUpperCase()].includes(part)),

  isValidName = check('Lorem, ipsum', ',');

console.log(isValidName);
```

If it's important for you to use a Regex, you can rewrite it like this:

```js
const
  check = (name, delimiter) =>
    name.split(delimiter).every(part =>
        part.match(/(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]/));

  isValidName = check('Lorem, ipsum', ',');

console.log(isValidName);
```

Note that in both cases, single-letter names will be considered invalid.

Comment: Be aware that lookbehind is not supported in all browsers. Moreover, why are you using lookbehind here?

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*)|((.*[A-Z].*[a-z].*))` will check for the presence of uppercase *and* lowercase letters. One issue you have is that you're using the `i` flag, which means the regex won't care about case. Additionally, it needs to check for an upper-case letter separately from a lower-case one. Having them both be options for each letter means that they can all be one case.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a cross-browser regex like

```
/^(?![A-Z ,.'-]+$)(?![a-z ,.'-]+$)[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/
```

It only contains two negative lookaheads that all current browsers support. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oYVKc4/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![A-Z ,.'-]+$)` - only uppercase letters, spaces, commas, dots, apostrophes and hyphens up to the end of string are not allowed
- `(?![a-z ,.'-]+$)` - only lowercase letters, spaces, commas, dots, apostrophes and hyphens up to the end of string are not allowed
- `[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+` - 1+ ASCII letters,  spaces, commas, dots, apostrophes and hyphens
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['abc A','ssss, S','abc','abc 12 A'];
var rx = /^(?![A-Z ,.'-]+$)(?![a-z ,.'-]+$)[a-zA-Z ,.'-]+$/;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  console.log(strs[i], '=>', rx.test(strs[i]));
}
```